# How can I hide the last 3 divs using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to select the last 3 divs using JQuery so far I've tried. But it doesn't seem to work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( "div.span4:nth-child(6), div.span4:nth-child(7), div.span4:nth-child(8)" ).
    addClass( "myClass" );

});
```

```html
<div class="row-fluid">

  <div class="span4"></div>
  <div class="span4"></div>
  <div class="span4"></div>
  <div class="span4"></div>
  <div class="span4"></div>
  <div class="span4"></div>
  <div class="span4"></div>
  <div class="span4"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Works fine here: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/XbaPbp.  Can you provide a (non-)working example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: It seems to be working fine here:
https://jsfiddle.net/pnsyu8p1/

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```js
$('.span4:gt(-4)').hide();
// It's simply "greater than fourth one from the end" ;)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row-fluid">

  <div class="span4">1</div>
  <div class="span4">2</div>
  <div class="span4">3</div>
  <div class="span4">4</div>
  <div class="span4">5</div>
  <div class="span4">6</div>
  <div class="span4">7</div>
  <div class="span4">8</div>

</div>
```

Comment: nice one! didnt know you can pass in -4 :)

Comment: tbh I didn't know it also before this question, that's why I think I'm hooked up on Stackoverflow - it forces me to think about those things I take for granted ;)

Comment: I already tested and it works. But, put a code snippet in your answer to demonstrate. I find that code snippets usually get positive upvotes

Comment: Absolutely, thats one of the main reasons I love SO. Learning new things everyday :)

Comment: Ok, here's my first SO snippet then, wasn't so hard :)

Comment: This is a good one as well. I never thought of using greater than.

Comment: It's also more in line with described requirements - it takes always last three elements, no mater how many exist.

Answer (score 2):

Seems working with nth-child(): http://jsfiddle.net/3b8su8f4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "div.span4:nth-child(6),div.span4:nth-child(7),div.span4:nth-child(8) " ).addClass( "myClass" );
});
```

Comment: If we do know the total number of items, as the example suggest, you can also write it like so: `$('.span4:nth-child(n+6)').hide();`

Comment: More accurate for the title:    $( "div.span4:nth-last-child(-n+3)" ).addClass( "myClass" );   http://jsfiddle.net/3b8su8f4/2/

Comment: I know, i just wanted to show off that the initial code was even working.

Answer (score 2):

`nth-last-child` should do?

```js
$('div.span4:nth-last-child(-n+3)').addClass('myClass');
```

```css
.span4 {
  background: #666;
}

.myClass {
  background: #0cc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4">1</div>
  <div class="span4">2</div>
  <div class="span4">3</div>
  <div class="span4">4</div>
  <div class="span4">5</div>
  <div class="span4">6</div>
  <div class="span4">7</div>
  <div class="span4">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys. These answers help a lot and fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector

```js
var divLength = $('div.span4').length;
$('div.span4:gt(' + (divLength - 4) + ')').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-fluid">

  <div class="span4">1</div>
  <div class="span4">2</div>
  <div class="span4">3</div>
  <div class="span4">4</div>
  <div class="span4">5</div>
  <div class="span4">6</div>
  <div class="span4">7</div>
  <div class="span4">8</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('div.span4').slice(-3).addClass('myClass');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsajuw4o/)